# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in android

Tags: android, json, string

I am reading json file from assets folder in my project in android. I am trying to convert String returned after reading json file into JSONObject. I googled alot but can't find fault in my code. Others are having success using this code. Anyone, kindly guide me if my approach is wrong or some fault is in my code.
At line - //1 , i get the error stated in title.

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream is;

        try 
        {
            is=am.open("places.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.close();
            String bufferString = new String(buffer);
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(bufferString);    //1
            JSONObject pjo = jo.getJSONObject("Places");
```

Comment: Did you debug the bufferString? or Log the bufferString?

Comment: You aren't actually reading anything from the asset, just allocating the buffer.

Comment: your buffer that should have the string in bytes was empty. You just declare it, but not put the correct values there.

Comment: Read the file contents first......just google it how to read file :P

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using JSONReader:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Available from API level 11. 
But I'm sure it's also available via the compatibility library v4

Comment: the link you provided..in that following the code, after reader.endObject(); line follows -> return new Message(image,lat,lon);  -> at this line, I get error stating : the constructor Message(String,String,String) is undefined